# Calculating light absorbed in solids

Tags: optics

I need a way to calculate what percentage of light will be absorbed when traveling through solids.

I cannot use Beer-Lambert, as that is apparently only for relatively dilute solutions, and not solids.

I have:

- The length of the path through the material
- The wavelength of the light
- Properties of the material the light is moving through

Does such a forumla exist? Is this purely intrinsic and just dependent on the material or on other factors?

If it does, is there already some useful sample data for basic materials like glass, polycarbonate plastic, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Light is absorbed exponentially. So if you have the optical properties of the material (for each wavelength of interest), then you’ll apply
$$
T=T_0 e^{-\tau L},
$$
where $T$ is the power transmitted through length $L$ at a particular wavelength, $T_0$ is the initial power, and $\tau$ is the power absorption coefficient per unit length. You can obtain $\tau$ from the optical density, complex refractive index, complex permittivity, and/or complex conductivity, depending on what you have.

Then the absorbed power, through energy conservation, is $A=T_0-T$.

This of course neglects reflections/scattering at interfaces and assumes that the light is already within the material.

Comment: One thing I forgot is that refractiveindex.info is a useful resource. Once you figure out what optical properties you have, you could ask another question about converting them to work for this purpose.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is also called the "linear attenuation coefficient" and it is effected by wavelength, right?

Comment: @TylerShellberg Yes, it depends on wavelength, and yes, you could call it the linear attenuation coefficient. But make sure you’re clear about whether the attenuation coefficient is referring to *power* or *field*. The attenuation coefficient is twice as large for power.